# How to specify static linking in makefile?

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, static-linking

I usually use the "--enable-static" option when running a configure script to statically link the resulting executable.

However, right now I am trying to compile [g3data](http://www.frantz.fi/software/g3data.php), which comes only with a makefile (no configure file). I tried adding the "-bstatic" option in the makefile (the "-static" option does not work on my system: Mac OS X 10.6.8, see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2252567) for an explanation), but while the compilation was successful and I can run the program, it was not statically linked...

What should I do to achieve static linking in a makefile like this? Here is what I have right now:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -bstatic
LIBS=`pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
LDFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -bstatic
#bindir ?= /usr/bin
#mandir ?= /usr/share/man

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $<

all: g3data

g3data: main.o sort.o points.o drawing.o #g3data.1.gz
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o g3data main.o sort.o points.o drawing.o $(LIBS) -bstatic
    strip g3data

main.o: main.c main.h strings.h vardefs.h

sort.o: sort.c main.h

points.o: points.c main.h

drawing.o: drawing.c main.h

#g3data.1.gz: g3data.sgml
#   rm -f *.1
#   onsgmls g3data.sgml | sgmlspl /usr/share/sgml/docbook/utils-0.6.14/helpers/docbook2man-spec.pl
#   gzip g3data.1

clean:
    rm -f *.o g3data g3data.1.gz *~ manpage.*

install:
    install g3data $(bindir)
    install g3data.1.gz $(mandir)/man1

uninstall:
    rm $(bindir)/g3data
```

Comment: Normally gcc uses the `-static` flag for static linking -- I would expect `-bstatic` to give you an unknown option error...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yes I noticed from most sources that you should use "-static", but apparently for OS X you should use "-bstatic". I've added a link to information on that in my question.

Comment: So... you're trying to link statically to a shared library?

Comment: @Beta I am trying to link to GTK2, and I did not intend to link to a shared library. However, I confess I am no familiar with makefiles. My goal is to create a statically linked executable that can run independent of any installed libraries.

Comment: This isn't a makefile problem, it's a linking problem. If any of those libraries are shared libraries, they don't contain all the information needed for static linking; you need the static versions of the libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `-bstatic` is the right option for your linker, and assuming you do have static versions of the necessary libraries, I would expect you need to put that option *before* the list of `$(LIBS)`, as if it's like the `-Bstatic` option for the GNU linker then it only affects libraries listed *after* the option.